# How to get the number of items in an enumerated type in Pascal?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, maxlength

```
program 
  Enumeration;
uses 
  crt;
type
  beverage = (coffee, tea, milk, water, coke, limejuice);
var
  drink:beverage; 
begin`enter code here`
  writeln('Which drink do you want?');
  writeln('You have ', *** , ' choices');
  readkey;
end.
```

What should i use in '***' here to get the number of elements in the beverage enumerated type in output ?
I used `sizeof()`, but it gives the byte value of type.
I'm using lazarus, fyi.

Answer (score 3):

[Succ(Ord(High(beverage)))](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/high.html) should give you the number of defined beverages.

Comment: It could be good to add a warning, that this is correct only if the values were not forced to "jump", like if the enumeration had had `milk=7` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ORD** and **HIGH-LOW** function:

```
ord(high(beverage)) - ord(low(beverage)) + 1
```

codes:

```
program 
  Enumeration;
uses 
  crt;
type
  beverage = (coffee, tea, milk, water, coke, limejuice);
var
  drink:beverage; 
begin`enter code here`
  writeln('Which drink do you want?');
  writeln('You have ', ord(high(beverage))-ord(low(beverage))+1 , ' choices');
  readkey;
end.
```

result:

```
Which drink do you want?
You have 6 choices
```